# Rotating an axis of rotation in webgl

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl

So I am not sure if my question is more of a programming question, more of a pure math question, or equally both.

Short version: I have a rotating sphere in webgl, but it isn't rotating the way I want it to. I *think* what I want is to rotate the sphere about an axis, and then rotate *that axis* about a second axis.

So I have downloaded and tweaked some javascript webgl code that renders an icosahedron and can animate its rotation along x, y, or z axes, either individually or simultaneously in a composite rotation group. I have some sense of how it is working.

I've also read ([such as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465969/sphere-rotating-in-several-directions-simultaneously)) that any rotation group of Euler angles actually just yields some new, net, single axis of rotation. Which means I can't get the animation I want by just using the rotations of those three axes.

So I think what I need is a new *kind* of rotation, that rotates the axis of rotation itself. But I am at a loss as for how to apply that to the matrix transformation.

- Would that be implemented as a separate transformation?
- Would it be included into the geometry of the y axis rotation?
- Would it be easier to implement by rotating the *camera* around the x axis?
- Should I cross-post this to math stack exchange for help with the pure math?

I would appreciate any help, whether high level conceptual suggestions or detailed code suggestions.

Below is the working snippet I'm currently using. It is rotating about the y axis, and I'd like that axis of rotation to rotate around the x axis. But that's not the same as just doing a rotation group around the x and y axis simultaneously - that just yields a single, composite rotation axis of the line y = x.

```js
var App = (function () {
function App(canvas) {
 this._canvas = canvas;
 this._ctx = canvas.getContext('webgl');
 this._ctx.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 this._canvas.setAttribute('width', this._canvas.clientWidth.toString());
 this._canvas.setAttribute('height', this._canvas.clientHeight.toString());
 this._config =
  {
   DrawMode: this._ctx.TRIANGLES,
   Quality: 3,
   ZoomLevel: -4,
   Rotation: {
    X: 0.0000,
    Y: 0.0100,
    Z: 0.0000
   }
  };
}
App.prototype._setData = function () {
 var ctx = this._ctx;
 var icosahedron = new Icosahedron3D(this._config.Quality);
 this._vertices = icosahedron.Points.reduce(function (a, b, i) { return i === 1 ? [a.x, a.y, a.z, b.x, b.y, b.z] : a.concat([b.x, b.y, b.z]); });
 this._indices = icosahedron.TriangleIndices;
 this._colors = this._generateColors(this._vertices);
 var vertex_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this._vertices), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 var color_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this._colors), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 var index_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this._indices), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 return {
  vertex: vertex_buffer,
  color: color_buffer,
  index: index_buffer
 };
};
App.prototype._generateColors = function (vertices) {
 var colors = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
  var cvalue = 0;
  var testvalue = 0;
  if (vertices[i] >= 0) testvalue++;
  if (vertices[i+1] >= 0) testvalue++;
  if (vertices[i+2] >= 0) testvalue++;
  else testvalue = 0;
  if (testvalue > 0) cvalue = 1;
  colors.push(cvalue);
  colors.push(cvalue);
  colors.push(cvalue);
 }
 return colors;
}
App.prototype._animate = function (proj_matrix, view_matrix, mov_matrix) {
 var _this = this;
 var ctx = this._ctx;
 var rotThetas = this._config.Rotation;
 var time_old = 0;
 var zoomLevel_old = 0;
 var execAnimation = function (time) {
  var dt = time - time_old;
  time_old = time;
  for (var axis in rotThetas) {
   var theta = rotThetas[axis];
   if (theta > 0.0 || theta < 0.0) {
    Matrix[("Rotate" + axis)](mov_matrix, dt * theta);
   }
  }
  if (Math.abs(_this._config.ZoomLevel - zoomLevel_old) >= 0.01) {
   view_matrix[14] = view_matrix[14] + (zoomLevel_old * -1) + _this._config.ZoomLevel;
   zoomLevel_old = _this._config.ZoomLevel;
  }
  ctx.enable(ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
  ctx.depthFunc(ctx.LEQUAL);
  ctx.clearDepth(1.0);
  ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, _this._canvas.width, _this._canvas.height);
  ctx.clear(ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Pmatrix, false, proj_matrix);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Vmatrix, false, view_matrix);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Mmatrix, false, mov_matrix);
  ctx.drawElements(_this._config.DrawMode, _this._indices.length, ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(execAnimation);
 };
 execAnimation(0);
};
App.prototype.Draw = function () {
 var buffers = this._setData();
 this._shader = App.UseQuarternionShaderProgram(this._ctx, buffers.vertex, buffers.color);
 var proj_matrix = new Float32Array(Matrix.GetProjection(40, this._canvas.width / this._canvas.height, 1, 100));
 var view_matrix = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]);
 var mov_matrix = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]);
 this._animate(proj_matrix, view_matrix, mov_matrix);
};
App.UseQuarternionVertShader = function (context) {
 var vertCode = "\n\t\t\tattribute vec3 position;\n\t\t\tattribute highp vec3 aVertexNormal;\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Pmatrix;\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Vmatrix;\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Mmatrix;\n\n\t\t\tattribute vec4 color;\n\t\t\tvarying lowp vec4 vColor;\n\n\t\t\tvarying vec3 vLightWeighting;\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uAmbientColor;\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uPointLightingColor;\n\n\t\t\tvoid main(void) {\n\t\t\t\tvec4 mvPosition = Mmatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\t\t\t\tgl_Position = Pmatrix*Vmatrix*mvPosition;\n\t\t\t\tgl_PointSize = 4.0;\n\t\t\t\tvColor = color;\n\n\t\t\t\tvec3 lightDirection = normalize(uPointLightingLocation - mvPosition.xyz);\n\t\t\t\tvec3 transformedNormal = vec3(Vmatrix) * aVertexNormal;\n\t\t\t\tfloat directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, lightDirection), 0.0);\n\t\t\t\tvLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uPointLightingColor * directionalLightWeighting;\n\t\t\t}";
 var vertShader = context.createShader(context.VERTEX_SHADER);
 context.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
 context.compileShader(vertShader);
 return vertShader;
};
App.UseVariableFragShader = function (context) {
 var fragCode = "\n\t\t\tprecision mediump float;\n\t\t\tvarying lowp vec4 vColor;\n\t\t\tvarying vec3 vLightWeighting;\n\t\t\tvoid main(void) {\n\t\t\t\tgl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb, 1.);\n\t\t\t}";
 var fragShader = context.createShader(context.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 context.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
 context.compileShader(fragShader);
 return fragShader;
};
App.UseQuarternionShaderProgram = function (ctx, vertex_buffer, color_buffer) {
 var vertShader = App.UseQuarternionVertShader(ctx);
 var fragShader = App.UseVariableFragShader(ctx);
 var shaderProgram = ctx.createProgram();
 ctx.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
 ctx.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
 ctx.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
 var Pmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Pmatrix");
 var Vmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Vmatrix");
 var Mmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Mmatrix");
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
 var position = ctx.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
 ctx.vertexAttribPointer(position, 3, ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(position);
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
 var color = ctx.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
 ctx.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(color);
 ctx.useProgram(shaderProgram);
 var ambientColor = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor");
 var pointLightingLocation = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPointLightingLocation");
 var pointLightingColor = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPointLightingColor");
 ctx.uniform3f(ambientColor, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
 ctx.uniform3f(pointLightingLocation, 0.0, 0.0, -20.0);
 ctx.uniform3f(pointLightingColor, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
 return {
  Pmatrix: Pmatrix,
  Vmatrix: Vmatrix,
  Mmatrix: Mmatrix,
  ShaderProgram: shaderProgram
 };
};
return App;
})();
var Matrix = (function () {
function Matrix() {
}
Matrix.GetProjection = function (angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
 var ang = Math.tan((angle * .5) * Math.PI / 180);
 return [
  0.5 / ang, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5 * a / ang, 0, 0,
  0, 0, -(zMax + zMin) / (zMax - zMin), -1,
  0, 0, (-2 * zMax * zMin) / (zMax - zMin), 0
 ];
};
Matrix.RotateX = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv1 = m[1], mv5 = m[5], mv9 = m[9];
 m[1] = m[1] * c - m[2] * s;
 m[5] = m[5] * c - m[6] * s;
 m[9] = m[9] * c - m[10] * s;
 m[2] = m[2] * c + mv1 * s;
 m[6] = m[6] * c + mv5 * s;
 m[10] = m[10] * c + mv9 * s;
};
Matrix.RotateY = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];
 m[0] = c * m[0] + s * m[2];
 m[4] = c * m[4] + s * m[6];
 m[8] = c * m[8] + s * m[10];
 m[2] = c * m[2] - s * mv0;
 m[6] = c * m[6] - s * mv4;
 m[10] = c * m[10] - s * mv8;
};
Matrix.RotateZ = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];
 m[0] = c * m[0] - s * m[1];
 m[4] = c * m[4] - s * m[5];
 m[8] = c * m[8] - s * m[9];
 m[1] = c * m[1] + s * mv0;
 m[5] = c * m[5] + s * mv4;
 m[9] = c * m[9] + s * mv8;
};
Matrix.Translate = function (a, b, c) {
 var d = b[0], e = b[1], s = b[2];
 if (!c || a == c) {
  a[12] = a[0] * d + a[4] * e + a[8] * s + a[12];
  a[13] = a[1] * d + a[5] * e + a[9] * s + a[13];
  a[14] = a[2] * d + a[6] * e + a[10] * s + a[14];
  a[15] = a[3] * d + a[7] * e + a[11] * s + a[15];
  return a;
 }
 var g = a[0], f = a[1], h = a[2], i = a[3], j = a[4], k = a[5], l = a[6], o = a[7], m = a[8], n = a[9], p = a[10], r = a[11];
 c[0] = g;
 c[1] = f;
 c[2] = h;
 c[3] = i;
 c[4] = j;
 c[5] = k;
 c[6] = l;
 c[7] = o;
 c[8] = m;
 c[9] = n;
 c[10] = p;
 c[11] = r;
 c[12] = g * d + j * e + m * s + a[12];
 c[13] = f * d + k * e + n * s + a[13];
 c[14] = h * d + l * e + p * s + a[14];
 c[15] = i * d + o * e + r * s + a[15];
 return c;
};
;
return Matrix;
})();
var Icosahedron3D = (function () {
function Icosahedron3D(quality) {
 this._quality = quality;
 this._calculateGeometry();
}
Icosahedron3D.prototype._calculateGeometry = function () {
 this.Points = [];
 this.TriangleIndices = [];
 this._middlePointIndexCache = {};
 this._index = 0;
 var t = (1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
 this._addVertex(-1, t, 0);
 this._addVertex(1, t, 0);
 this._addVertex(-1, -t, 0);
 this._addVertex(1, -t, 0);
 this._addVertex(0, -1, t);
 this._addVertex(0, 1, t);
 this._addVertex(0, -1, -t);
 this._addVertex(0, 1, -t);
 this._addVertex(t, 0, -1);
 this._addVertex(t, 0, 1);
 this._addVertex(-t, 0, -1);
 this._addVertex(-t, 0, 1);
 this._addFace(0, 11, 5);
 this._addFace(0, 5, 1);
 this._addFace(0, 1, 7);
 this._addFace(0, 7, 10);
 this._addFace(0, 10, 11);
 this._addFace(1, 5, 9);
 this._addFace(5, 11, 4);
 this._addFace(11, 10, 2);
 this._addFace(10, 7, 6);
 this._addFace(7, 1, 8);
 this._addFace(3, 9, 4);
 this._addFace(3, 4, 2);
 this._addFace(3, 2, 6);
 this._addFace(3, 6, 8);
 this._addFace(3, 8, 9);
 this._addFace(4, 9, 5);
 this._addFace(2, 4, 11);
 this._addFace(6, 2, 10);
 this._addFace(8, 6, 7);
 this._addFace(9, 8, 1);
 this._refineVertices();
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._addVertex = function (x, y, z) {
 var length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
 this.Points.push({
  x: x / length,
  y: y / length,
  z: z / length
 });
 return this._index++;
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._addFace = function (x, y, z) {
 this.TriangleIndices.push(x);
 this.TriangleIndices.push(y);
 this.TriangleIndices.push(z);
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._refineVertices = function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < this._quality; i++) {
  var faceCount = this.TriangleIndices.length;
  for (var face = 0; face < faceCount; face += 3) {
   var x1 = this.TriangleIndices[face];
   var y1 = this.TriangleIndices[face + 1];
   var z1 = this.TriangleIndices[face + 2];
   var x2 = this._getMiddlePoint(x1, y1);
   var y2 = this._getMiddlePoint(y1, z1);
   var z2 = this._getMiddlePoint(z1, x1);
   this._addFace(x1, x2, z2);
   this._addFace(y1, y2, x2);
   this._addFace(z1, z2, y2);
   this._addFace(x2, y2, z2);
  }
 }
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._getMiddlePoint = function (p1, p2) {
 var firstIsSmaller = p1 < p2;
 var smallerIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p1 : p2;
 var greaterIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p2 : p1;
 var key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;
 var p = this._middlePointIndexCache[key];
 if (p !== undefined)
  p;
 var point1 = this.Points[p1];
 var point2 = this.Points[p2];
 var middle = {
  x: (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0,
  y: (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0,
  z: (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0,
 };
 var i = this._addVertex(middle.x, middle.y, middle.z);
 this._middlePointIndexCache[key] = i;
 return i;
};
return Icosahedron3D;
})();
(function () {
var app = new App(document.getElementById('canvas'));
app.Draw();
})();
```

```html
<body style="background-color: rgb(55,55,55);">
<canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" />
</body>
```

Comment: You might find it's much easier to deal with GLSL using [multline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They'll be more easily ediable and readable. You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html) helpful.

Comment: @gman Thanks! The notation was definitely a beast. I will take a look at these articles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the simplest solution seems to be the notion of moving the view instead of the object.

To do this, I keep the existing rotation axis information which is applied to the mov matrix unchanged, but added a new triple to provide rotation axis information to be applied to the view matrix:

```js
var App = (function () {
function App(canvas) {
 this._canvas = canvas;
 this._ctx = canvas.getContext('webgl');
 this._ctx.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 this._canvas.setAttribute('width', this._canvas.clientWidth.toString());
 this._canvas.setAttribute('height', this._canvas.clientHeight.toString());
 this._config =
  {
   DrawMode: this._ctx.TRIANGLES,
   Quality: 3,
   ZoomLevel: -4,
   MovRotation: {
    X: 0.00000,
    Y: 0.01000,
    Z: 0.00000
   },
   ViewRotation: {
    X: 0.00100,
    Y: 0.00000,
    Z: 0.00000
   }
  };
}
App.prototype._setData = function () {
 var ctx = this._ctx;
 var icosahedron = new Icosahedron3D(this._config.Quality);
 this._vertices = icosahedron.Points.reduce(function (a, b, i) { return i === 1 ? [a.x, a.y, a.z, b.x, b.y, b.z] : a.concat([b.x, b.y, b.z]); });
 this._indices = icosahedron.TriangleIndices;
 this._colors = this._generateColors(this._vertices);
 var vertex_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this._vertices), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 var color_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this._colors), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 var index_buffer = ctx.createBuffer();
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
 ctx.bufferData(ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this._indices), ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
 return {
  vertex: vertex_buffer,
  color: color_buffer,
  index: index_buffer
 };
};
App.prototype._generateColors = function (vertices) {
 var colors = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
  var cvalue = 0;
  var testvalue = 0;
  if (vertices[i] >= 0) testvalue++;
  if (vertices[i+1] >= 0) testvalue++;
  if (vertices[i+2] >= 0) testvalue++;
  else testvalue = 0;
  if (testvalue > 0) cvalue = 1;
  colors.push(cvalue);
  colors.push(cvalue);
  colors.push(cvalue);
 }
 return colors;
}
App.prototype._animate = function (proj_matrix, view_matrix, mov_matrix) {
 var _this = this;
 var ctx = this._ctx;
 var movThetas = this._config.MovRotation;
 var viewThetas = this._config.ViewRotation
 var time_old = 0;
 var zoomLevel_old = 0;
 var execAnimation = function (time) {
  var dt = time - time_old;
  time_old = time;
  for (var m_axis in movThetas) {
   var theta = movThetas[m_axis];
   if (theta > 0.0 || theta < 0.0) {
    Matrix[("Rotate" + m_axis)](mov_matrix, dt * theta);
   }
  }
  for (var v_axis in viewThetas) {
      var theta = viewThetas[v_axis];
      if (theta > 0.0 || theta < 0.0) {
       Matrix[("Rotate" + v_axis)](view_matrix, dt * theta);
      }
  }
  if (Math.abs(_this._config.ZoomLevel - zoomLevel_old) >= 0.01) {
   view_matrix[14] = view_matrix[14] + (zoomLevel_old * -1) + _this._config.ZoomLevel;
   zoomLevel_old = _this._config.ZoomLevel;
  }
  ctx.enable(ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
  ctx.depthFunc(ctx.LEQUAL);
  ctx.clearDepth(1.0);
  ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, _this._canvas.width, _this._canvas.height);
  ctx.clear(ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Pmatrix, false, proj_matrix);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Vmatrix, false, view_matrix);
  ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_this._shader.Mmatrix, false, mov_matrix);
  ctx.drawElements(_this._config.DrawMode, _this._indices.length, ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(execAnimation);
 };
 execAnimation(0);
};
App.prototype.Draw = function () {
 var buffers = this._setData();
 this._shader = App.UseQuarternionShaderProgram(this._ctx, buffers.vertex, buffers.color);
 var proj_matrix = new Float32Array(Matrix.GetProjection(40, this._canvas.width / this._canvas.height, 1, 100));
 var view_matrix = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]);
 var mov_matrix = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]);
 this._animate(proj_matrix, view_matrix, mov_matrix);
};
App.UseQuarternionVertShader = function (context) {
 var vertCode = "\n\t\t\tattribute vec3 position;\n\t\t\tattribute highp vec3 aVertexNormal;\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Pmatrix;\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Vmatrix;\n\t\t\tuniform mat4 Mmatrix;\n\n\t\t\tattribute vec4 color;\n\t\t\tvarying lowp vec4 vColor;\n\n\t\t\tvarying vec3 vLightWeighting;\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uAmbientColor;\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;\n\t\t\tuniform vec3 uPointLightingColor;\n\n\t\t\tvoid main(void) {\n\t\t\t\tvec4 mvPosition = Mmatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\t\t\t\tgl_Position = Pmatrix*Vmatrix*mvPosition;\n\t\t\t\tgl_PointSize = 4.0;\n\t\t\t\tvColor = color;\n\n\t\t\t\tvec3 lightDirection = normalize(uPointLightingLocation - mvPosition.xyz);\n\t\t\t\tvec3 transformedNormal = vec3(Vmatrix) * aVertexNormal;\n\t\t\t\tfloat directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, lightDirection), 0.0);\n\t\t\t\tvLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uPointLightingColor * directionalLightWeighting;\n\t\t\t}";
 var vertShader = context.createShader(context.VERTEX_SHADER);
 context.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
 context.compileShader(vertShader);
 return vertShader;
};
App.UseVariableFragShader = function (context) {
 var fragCode = "\n\t\t\tprecision mediump float;\n\t\t\tvarying lowp vec4 vColor;\n\t\t\tvarying vec3 vLightWeighting;\n\t\t\tvoid main(void) {\n\t\t\t\tgl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb, 1.);\n\t\t\t}";
 var fragShader = context.createShader(context.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 context.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
 context.compileShader(fragShader);
 return fragShader;
};
App.UseQuarternionShaderProgram = function (ctx, vertex_buffer, color_buffer) {
 var vertShader = App.UseQuarternionVertShader(ctx);
 var fragShader = App.UseVariableFragShader(ctx);
 var shaderProgram = ctx.createProgram();
 ctx.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
 ctx.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
 ctx.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
 var Pmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Pmatrix");
 var Vmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Vmatrix");
 var Mmatrix = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Mmatrix");
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
 var position = ctx.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
 ctx.vertexAttribPointer(position, 3, ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(position);
 ctx.bindBuffer(ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
 var color = ctx.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
 ctx.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, ctx.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(color);
 ctx.useProgram(shaderProgram);
 var ambientColor = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor");
 var pointLightingLocation = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPointLightingLocation");
 var pointLightingColor = ctx.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPointLightingColor");
 ctx.uniform3f(ambientColor, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
 ctx.uniform3f(pointLightingLocation, 0.0, 0.0, -20.0);
 ctx.uniform3f(pointLightingColor, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
 return {
  Pmatrix: Pmatrix,
  Vmatrix: Vmatrix,
  Mmatrix: Mmatrix,
  ShaderProgram: shaderProgram
 };
};
return App;
})();
var Matrix = (function () {
function Matrix() {
}
Matrix.GetProjection = function (angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
 var ang = Math.tan((angle * .5) * Math.PI / 180);
 return [
  0.5 / ang, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5 * a / ang, 0, 0,
  0, 0, -(zMax + zMin) / (zMax - zMin), -1,
  0, 0, (-2 * zMax * zMin) / (zMax - zMin), 0
 ];
};
Matrix.RotateX = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv1 = m[1], mv5 = m[5], mv9 = m[9];
 m[1] = m[1] * c - m[2] * s;
 m[5] = m[5] * c - m[6] * s;
 m[9] = m[9] * c - m[10] * s;
 m[2] = m[2] * c + mv1 * s;
 m[6] = m[6] * c + mv5 * s;
 m[10] = m[10] * c + mv9 * s;
};
Matrix.RotateY = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];
 m[0] = c * m[0] + s * m[2];
 m[4] = c * m[4] + s * m[6];
 m[8] = c * m[8] + s * m[10];
 m[2] = c * m[2] - s * mv0;
 m[6] = c * m[6] - s * mv4;
 m[10] = c * m[10] - s * mv8;
};
Matrix.RotateZ = function (m, angle) {
 var c = Math.cos(angle);
 var s = Math.sin(angle);
 var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];
 m[0] = c * m[0] - s * m[1];
 m[4] = c * m[4] - s * m[5];
 m[8] = c * m[8] - s * m[9];
 m[1] = c * m[1] + s * mv0;
 m[5] = c * m[5] + s * mv4;
 m[9] = c * m[9] + s * mv8;
};
Matrix.Translate = function (a, b, c) {
 var d = b[0], e = b[1], s = b[2];
 if (!c || a == c) {
  a[12] = a[0] * d + a[4] * e + a[8] * s + a[12];
  a[13] = a[1] * d + a[5] * e + a[9] * s + a[13];
  a[14] = a[2] * d + a[6] * e + a[10] * s + a[14];
  a[15] = a[3] * d + a[7] * e + a[11] * s + a[15];
  return a;
 }
 var g = a[0], f = a[1], h = a[2], i = a[3], j = a[4], k = a[5], l = a[6], o = a[7], m = a[8], n = a[9], p = a[10], r = a[11];
 c[0] = g;
 c[1] = f;
 c[2] = h;
 c[3] = i;
 c[4] = j;
 c[5] = k;
 c[6] = l;
 c[7] = o;
 c[8] = m;
 c[9] = n;
 c[10] = p;
 c[11] = r;
 c[12] = g * d + j * e + m * s + a[12];
 c[13] = f * d + k * e + n * s + a[13];
 c[14] = h * d + l * e + p * s + a[14];
 c[15] = i * d + o * e + r * s + a[15];
 return c;
};
;
return Matrix;
})();
var Icosahedron3D = (function () {
function Icosahedron3D(quality) {
 this._quality = quality;
 this._calculateGeometry();
}
Icosahedron3D.prototype._calculateGeometry = function () {
 this.Points = [];
 this.TriangleIndices = [];
 this._middlePointIndexCache = {};
 this._index = 0;
 var t = (1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
 this._addVertex(-1, t, 0);
 this._addVertex(1, t, 0);
 this._addVertex(-1, -t, 0);
 this._addVertex(1, -t, 0);
 this._addVertex(0, -1, t);
 this._addVertex(0, 1, t);
 this._addVertex(0, -1, -t);
 this._addVertex(0, 1, -t);
 this._addVertex(t, 0, -1);
 this._addVertex(t, 0, 1);
 this._addVertex(-t, 0, -1);
 this._addVertex(-t, 0, 1);
 this._addFace(0, 11, 5);
 this._addFace(0, 5, 1);
 this._addFace(0, 1, 7);
 this._addFace(0, 7, 10);
 this._addFace(0, 10, 11);
 this._addFace(1, 5, 9);
 this._addFace(5, 11, 4);
 this._addFace(11, 10, 2);
 this._addFace(10, 7, 6);
 this._addFace(7, 1, 8);
 this._addFace(3, 9, 4);
 this._addFace(3, 4, 2);
 this._addFace(3, 2, 6);
 this._addFace(3, 6, 8);
 this._addFace(3, 8, 9);
 this._addFace(4, 9, 5);
 this._addFace(2, 4, 11);
 this._addFace(6, 2, 10);
 this._addFace(8, 6, 7);
 this._addFace(9, 8, 1);
 this._refineVertices();
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._addVertex = function (x, y, z) {
 var length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
 this.Points.push({
  x: x / length,
  y: y / length,
  z: z / length
 });
 return this._index++;
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._addFace = function (x, y, z) {
 this.TriangleIndices.push(x);
 this.TriangleIndices.push(y);
 this.TriangleIndices.push(z);
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._refineVertices = function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < this._quality; i++) {
  var faceCount = this.TriangleIndices.length;
  for (var face = 0; face < faceCount; face += 3) {
   var x1 = this.TriangleIndices[face];
   var y1 = this.TriangleIndices[face + 1];
   var z1 = this.TriangleIndices[face + 2];
   var x2 = this._getMiddlePoint(x1, y1);
   var y2 = this._getMiddlePoint(y1, z1);
   var z2 = this._getMiddlePoint(z1, x1);
   this._addFace(x1, x2, z2);
   this._addFace(y1, y2, x2);
   this._addFace(z1, z2, y2);
   this._addFace(x2, y2, z2);
  }
 }
};
Icosahedron3D.prototype._getMiddlePoint = function (p1, p2) {
 var firstIsSmaller = p1 < p2;
 var smallerIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p1 : p2;
 var greaterIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p2 : p1;
 var key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;
 var p = this._middlePointIndexCache[key];
 if (p !== undefined)
  p;
 var point1 = this.Points[p1];
 var point2 = this.Points[p2];
 var middle = {
  x: (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0,
  y: (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0,
  z: (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0,
 };
 var i = this._addVertex(middle.x, middle.y, middle.z);
 this._middlePointIndexCache[key] = i;
 return i;
};
return Icosahedron3D;
})();
(function () {
var app = new App(document.getElementById('canvas'));
app.Draw();
})();
```

```html
<body style="background-color: rgb(55,55,55);">
<canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" />
</body>
```